# Implementing my own ArrayList using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a project I have been assigned in java and I have to basically create my own class that mimics basic features of the ArrayList class.

I have to do it in the format shown below using these variables but I am stuck on one part. When the array fills up I want to make a new one with 10 extra spaces, then copy all the old array elements to the new one and use that from now on. How do I make my program automatically use this array from now on? Because it will continue to use the first array.

```
public MyArrayList()
{
    array = new String[10];
    arraySize = 10;
    arrayElements = 0;
}

public void add (String string)
{
    if (arrayElements < arraySize)
    {
        array[arrayElements] = string;
        arrayElements++;
    } else
    {
        arraySize += 10;
        arrayElements++;
        String[] array2 = new String[arraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrElements;i++)
        {
            array2[i] = array[i];
        }
        //missing code here I think?
        array2[arrayElements] = string;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `arrayElements++;` should come after you copy #arrayElements over to a new array.

Answer (score 4):

Assign `array2` to the `array` reference. Something like,

```
//missing code here I think?
array2[arrayElements] = string;
array = array2;
```

Or, use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29) and something like

```
arraySize += 10;
arrayElements++;
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, arraySize); // <-- will pad with zeros.
```

Comment: I'm confused, how can I assign array the value of array2? array2 will be double the size? I want the code to be able to continue, so I can keep adding items and it will keep updating the size of the array. My problem is that when it gets to the 11th element, it will try to add the element to array still, instead of array2. I need to make array2 the main array for the object essentially.

Comment: You'd assign the reference back to `array`. And it would be the same array that `array2` refered to (the doubled array).

Comment: @toastedDeli The `array` field is a *reference* to the array, not the array itself. `array2` is a reference to another array. `array = array2` updates the reference stored in `array` to refer to the other array. The first array is then unreferenced, and will be deleted / garbage collected by the JVM.

Comment: I updated my code to include array = array2 where I said missing code should be but I still get an exception? I think I understand what you mean about the reference changes but I can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 1):

`MyArrayList` uses `array` to hold its contents; in `add` you have created a new version of this in `array2`; just assign that to `array`.

Comment: I cant assign array2 to array though because its double the size? :(

Comment: Have you tried?  I mean just `array = array2`, not trying to copy individual elements.

Comment: It's okay I got it :-) Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution to increase the size of your array

```
String[] array2 = new String[array.length + 10];
System.arraycopy(array , 0, array2 , 0, array.length);
array =  array2 ;
```

Comment: maybe you could add a few words to make this a better answer, maybe set arraySize to array.length + 10, maybe use newArray instead of array2...

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

- You create a new temporary array (`array2`) and copy existing values, but you don't update the `array` field to point to the new array.
- You increment `arrayElements` too early.

Your code should be (pseudo-code):

```
add(newVal) {
    if (array is full) {
        newarray = new [array.size + extra]
        copy values from array to newarray
        array = newarray
    }
    add newVal to array and increment value count
}
```

See. You should only add new value in one place.
That is the DRY principle ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).